# Store locator w/ google maps in classic ASP

Tags: google-maps, asp-classic

I can't find anything on how to create a store locator with google maps using classic ASP (not .net). Can anyone help me out with this? I have looked everywhere.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what kinds of stores you want to locate?  What is your data source?

Comment: If this page (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html) Was in ASP instead of PHP, would that be the sort of thing you were looking for?

Comment: Agreed, are you looking to display on google map or just open a page in google local? With the api, the server side stuff supplies the location information to the produced javascript, or you can even do the whole thing in javascript.

Comment: Do you have to develop something custom? There are hosted store locators that will work with any site. See: http://www.easylocator.net/

Answer (score 1):

Very little of this would have anything with your server side code to do.

If you took the AJAX-aproach (apropriate since you're using gmaps), your backend code would need to provide a list of stores with lat/lng location and perhaps states for further filtering.

This could be as simple as returning javascript (JSONP) with the data wrapped in a callback function:

[YourJSONPDataScript.asp]

```
<%

Response.Write "updateMyMapData(["

Do While Not Rs.Eof

  Response.Write "{ lat: " & Rs("Lat") & ", lng: " & Rs("Lng") & " }"

  Rs.MoveNext

  If Not Rs.Eof Response.Write ", "

Loop

Response.Write "]);"

%>
```

The main benefit begin the ability to port this to any other plattform by just changing the code that generates your JSONP-data :-)

And finally your HTML-page would contain a script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateMyMapData(stores) {

      for (var i=0; i < stores.length; i++) {

        var store = stores[i];

        // do stuff with store.lat, store.lng, add markers to map and populate select boxes.

      }

    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/YourJSONPDataScript.asp">
</script>
```